# Reference and create dataframes through loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have many dataframes that are named the same except for a suffix. I need to perform the same operation on these dataframes and would like to streamline this process through a loop. I am trying to figure out how to reference the dataframes through a loop over the list of suffixes. For example, something along the lines of:

```
for i in [a,b,c,d,e]:
     score_i=r2_score(df_i['col1'],df_i['col2']
```

and this would perform the same operation on all 5 dataframes and create 5 new variables. However, I'm not sure how to set this up without an error. Any advice would be appreciated - thanks!

Comment: If you're creating a lot of separate, similarly named variables, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: What about referencing dataframes that have already been created through string suffixes in a loop?

Comment: Not good. Don't create them that way.